# SQL Server : find break in dates to show unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have developed a solution to a problem (I think), and I am keen to see if there is a better way around this, as I can't help but feel there is a better way.

The problem: a company name, and a move in date are shown. The company could leave, another company come in and then the original company could come back. To make this problem a bit tricky, there may be rogue dates for a company in there. Best way to explain it is via the table:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeiGY.jpg)

What I need to extract, is only the first time a company moved in, until it is broken by a different company and so on.

The code I have is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpData') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE #tmpData
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpData
(
    COMPANY_NAME NVARCHAR(30),
    DATE_MOVED_IN DATETIME,
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    UNIQUE_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpData(COMPANY_NAME, DATE_MOVED_IN)
    SELECT 'ABC LTD','01/01/2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC LTD','01/04/2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XYZ LTD','01/10/2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC LTD','01/12/2017';

DECLARE @intMinID INT,
        @intMaxID INT,
        @strNextComp NVARCHAR(50),
        @strCurrentComp NVARCHAR(50),
        @strPreviousComp NVARCHAR(50),
        @intMaxUID INT;

SELECT  
    @intMinID = MIN(TD.ID),
    @intMaxID = MAX(TD.ID)
FROM    
    #tmpData AS TD

UPDATE TD
SET TD.UNIQUE_ID = 1
FROM #tmpData AS TD
WHERE TD.ID = @intMinID;

WHILE @intMinID <= @intMaxID
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        @strCurrentComp = TD.COMPANY_NAME
    FROM    
        #tmpData AS TD
    WHERE   
        TD.ID = @intMinID;

    SELECT  
        @strNextComp = TD.COMPANY_NAME
    FROM    
        #tmpData AS TD
    WHERE   
        TD.ID = (@intMinID + 1)

    SELECT  
        @strPreviousComp = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                             FROM #tmpData AS TD
                                             WHERE TD.ID = (@intMinID - 1))
                                    THEN TD.COMPANY_NAME
                                    ELSE 'No Company Exists'
                           END
    FROM    
        #tmpData AS TD
    WHERE   
        TD.ID = (@intMinID - 1)

    SELECT  
        @intMaxUID = MAX(TD.UNIQUE_ID)
    FROM    
        #tmpData AS TD

    IF(@strPreviousComp IS NULL)
        PRINT 'Nothing to do'
    ELSE IF((@strCurrentComp <> @strNextComp) AND (@strCurrentComp = @strPreviousComp)) 
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE TD
        SET TD.UNIQUE_ID = @intMaxUID
        FROM #tmpData AS TD
        WHERE TD.ID = @intMinID;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TD
        SET TD.UNIQUE_ID = @intMaxUID + 1
        FROM #tmpData AS TD
        WHERE TD.ID = @intMinID;
    END 

    SET @intMinID = @intMinID + 1;
END

SELECT   
    COMPANY_NAME, MIN(DATE_MOVED_IN) AS DATE_MOVED_IN
FROM
    #tmpData
GROUP BY 
    COMPANY_NAME, UNIQUE_ID
ORDER BY 
    UNIQUE_ID ASC
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in a more efficient way, or if any errors are spotted, feedback is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Leo

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: A set-based approach is superior to this looping, either via a gaps/islands approach, or `LEAD()`/`LAG()` approach, both answers below look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lag() should do it...

```
with CTE as
(
select Company_Name, Date_Moved_in, lag(Company_Name) over (order by Date_Moved_In) as PrevComp
from #TempTable
)
select Company_Name, Date_Moved_In
from CTE
where PrevComp <> Company_Name
or PrevComp is null
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday, never heard of LAG before, but it is perfect for this scenario. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the difference in row number logic to classify continuous dates by company into one group. Run the inner query alone to see how groups are assigned.

Thereafter, just `group by` the company and previously classified group to get the first date moved in.

```
select company_name,min(date_moved_in) 
from (
select t.*,
row_number() over(order by date_moved_in)
-row_number() over(partition by company_name order by date_moved_in) as grp
from #tmpData t
) x
group by company_name,grp
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer, this also works and is a lot neater than my solution.